# How to pass variables from VBScript to batch?

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I'm trying to pass parameters from VBScript to batch.

This is my VBScript:

```vb
Var1 = "foo"
Var2 = "bar"
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run "T.bat  "& Var1 & Var2
```

and this is my batch file:

```batch
@echo off
echo %1
echo %2
pause>nul
```

Comment: Nice but what goes wrong? Some error message(s)? Unexpected behaviour? Please [edit] your question…

Comment: You need a space between parameters in batch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a space between the two arguments, otherwise the batch file will see just a single argument.

```
WshShell.Run "T.bat  "& Var1 & Var2
```

becomes

```
WshShell.Run "T.bat  foobar"
```

To avoid the inadvertent concatenation change this:

```
WshShell.Run "T.bat  "& Var1 & Var2
```

into this:

```
WshShell.Run "T.bat "& Var1 & " " & Var2
```

or (better) this:

```
WshShell.Run "T.bat """& Var1 & """ """ & Var2 & """"
```

The additional double quotes are for handling spaces in the arguments. You can make that a little more readable by using a quoting function:

```
Function qq(str)
  qq = """" & str & """"
End Function

WshShell.Run "T.bat "& qq(Var1) & " " & qq(Var2)
```

---

As a side note: in your batch file you may want to use `%~1` and `%~2` instead of just `%1` and `%2`. The tilde removes outer double quotes from parameters.

Comment: Thank you exeactly wahta i was locking forrrr