# Calling .cmd file from VBScript with parameters

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

I have an a function in VBScript that downloads a file using the URL. As it is taking some time to download the file, I am planning to move this function to a separate vbs file, which I am planning to run using a .cmd file.

VBScript file:

```
sUrl = WScript.Arguments(0)
sFilePath = WScript.Arguments(1)
sBarcode = WScript.Arguments(2)

DownloadInvoiceToLocal sUrl, sFilePath, sBarcode 

Public Sub DownloadInvoiceToLocal1(sUrl, sFilePath, sBarcode) 
    Dim Url
    Url =  sUrl 
    Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = createobject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = createobject("Adodb.Stream")
    xHttp.Open "GET", Url, False
    xHttp.Send

    With bStrm
        .Type = 1 '//binary
        .Open
        .Write xHttp.responseBody
        .SaveToFile sFilePath & sBarcode & ".pdf", 2 '//overwrite
    End With  
End Sub
```

I want to pass three parameters to this vbs file from vbscript file through .cmd file.

Batch file:

```
C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cscript downloader.vbs argument1, argument2, argument3
```

How can I access these parameters here?

And how can I call the .cmd file with parameters from my VBScript file?

Comment: `downloader.vbs argument1, argument2, argument3` -> `downloader.vbs argument1 argument2 argument3`

Comment: Do you want to run VBScript from batch or batch from VBScript?

Comment: I want to run a batch from vbscript.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass variables from VBScript to batch?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40824085/1630171)

Comment: So will it make any difference in converting the .vbs file to .bat. Sorry if this is a silly question, as I not familiar with .bat files

Comment: .bat and .cmd are exactly the same. converting the VBScript code to batch is also possible, but requires an external program like `curl` or `wget`.

Comment: So if I convert the .vbs file to .bat, I can execute the .bat to accept my parameters from vbscript code right? Can you share with a simple sample for this.

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about. After you converted the VBScript to a batch file (more specifically re-implemented the functionality of the VBScript in a batch file) there is no VBScript anymore.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I have a separate vb script application from where I would like to execute this bat file with 3 parameters .

Comment: Then instead of running the VBScript with 3 parameters you would run the batch file with those 3 parameters.